# UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue: always produces black

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicolor

I have come across many instances when I try to make custom color through code and the result is quite different from Photoshop, e.g

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(160/255) green:(97/255) blue:(5/255) alpha:1];
```

the resultant color is blackish, whereas it should me something like yellow. When working using sliders, the result is as expected.

Is there a problem with my Xcode or it is a general issue?

Comment: No down vote from me but some criticism: this is quite basic C. Please read attentively a comprehensive C tutorial - fundamental things such as this are covered in there. Furthermore, please use tags appropriately. As a developer who doesn't use Xcode, it especially annoys me that almost all iOS development related questions misuse the "xcode" tag. Its tag wiki says: "...for questions related to the IDE **itself**. If your question wouldn't be different **if you used vi and make, this tag should not be used**".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Dividing integers results in integer division that essentially means truncating the fractional part of the result. Use

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(160/255.0) green:(97/255.0) blue:(5/255.0) alpha:1.0]
```

instead.

Comment: will have to wait 4 mins to accept thanku ... i was being a bone head

Comment: bah, too much time in Swift has made me forget that not all languages will autocast to the field type.

Answer (score 5):

colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha , each parameter specified as a value from 0.0(MIN) to 1.0 (MAX)

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(160/255.0f) green:(97/255.0f) blue:(5/255.0f) alpha:1];
```